# How to set font custom font to Spinner text programmatically?

Tags: android, fonts, spinner, android-spinner, android-fonts

I have a ttf font file in my assets folder. I know how to use it for textviews with:

```
Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
textview1.setTypeface(externalFont);
```

I have defined look for my spinner text in it's own xml file (as usuall in android):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

I just can't reference this textview from code, i always get null pointer exceptions. E.g. i tried:

```
TextView spinner_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
spinner_text.setTypeface(externalFont);
```

Is it possible to select my external font even for my spinner text defined in it's own xml?

Thank you.

## EDIT with answer:

This works:

```
String [] items = new String[2];
    items[0]="Something1";
    items[1]="Something2";

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.spinaca, items) {

         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                 Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
                 ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                 return v;
         }


         public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                  View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

                 Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt.ttf");
                 ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
                 v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                 return v;
         }
 };


     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                                 
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It may be necessary to add

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

To your list of imports at the top of your file. For some reason Eclipse doesn't make this suggestion when it doesn't recognize the ViewGroup class involved in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.. After a long struggle, I have found this. This saved my day atlast

Comment: thanks for adding answer!

Comment: Very Nice questions...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is what worked for me (using ideas both from [CommonsWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485512/56285) and [gsanllorente's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8955518/56285) answers):

```
private static class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    // Initialise custom font, for example:
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                        "fonts/Blambot.otf");

    // (In reality I used a manager which caches the Typeface objects)
    // Typeface font = FontManager.getInstance().getFont(getContext(), BLAMBOT);

    private MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    // Affects default (closed) state of the spinner
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setTypeface(font);
        return view;
    }

    // Affects opened state of the spinner
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setTypeface(font);
        return view;
    }
}
```

If you, like me, originally populated the Spinner using `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()` and an array resource (as in [Spinner documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)), then you'd use MySpinnerAdapter like this:

```
MySpinnerAdapter<String> adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(
        getContext(),
        R.layout.view_spinner_item,
        Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array))
);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Great! I went even further and created an `assignAdapterWithOptions(Spinner spinner, int textArrayResId)` method, getting the context from `spinner.getContext()` and assigning the adapter to the spinner inside it (spinner layouts are stander to my whole app)

Comment: This help me alot.Thanks...@Jonik

Answer (score 24):

You would apply the font through your own custom `SpinnerAdapter`, in `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`.

Comment: I edited my question with my latest problem, could you please tell what am i doing wrong. Tnx

Comment: @DixieFlatline: you need to add an import for `android.view.ViewGroup`, presumably

Answer (score 15):

If you implement your Adapter in another file, you can access the "getAssets()" function from the constructor of the Adapter, as you have the Context as a parameter.

```
public class YourItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
int recurso;
Typeface tf;

public YourItemAdapter(Context _context, int _resource,
        List<String> _items) {

    super(_context, _resource, _items);
    recurso=_resource;
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),"font/digital-7.ttf");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //You can use the new tf here.
    TextView spinner_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    spinner_text.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was kind of useful, even though it did not work for me: 
`findViewById(R.id.text1)` didn't seem to find the TextView, although the ID was correct. Some other problems in this code: 1) missing return statement in `getView()`, 2) unused field `recurso`, 3) some style issues like naming a variable `spinner_text` (should be `spinnerText`). [Here's what worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25510848/56285).

Comment: @Jonik : Thanks for keeping that link... It worked even in 2024...

Answer (score 4):

Try this create custom custom_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.xxxx.xxxx.CheckedTextViewC

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"

    />
```

Create custom CheckedtextView like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;

public class CheckedTextViewC extends CheckedTextView {

    public CheckedTextViewC(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CheckedTextViewC(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CheckedTextViewC(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        if(!this.isInEditMode()){
        Typeface normalTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Light.ttf");

        if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
            super.setTypeface(boldTypeface/*, -1*/);
        } else {
            super.setTypeface(normalTypeface/*, -1*/);
        }
        }

    }
}
```

implemente the new layout

```
adapter= new ArrayAdapter <String>(Menu.this,R.layout.custom_spinner, list);
```

Comment: I think this would be better , because you don't have to get your hand dirty on adapter , and you can use this CustomTextview anywhere else in your App .

Answer (score 2):

This is the continuation of my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51100507/787399

> For the compatibility reasons, you can use the styles and customized
>   classes against the widgets in Android. Although above Android level
>   15, new `/res/font` resource folders were introduced:
>
> [Font Resources in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources)

Step 1: declare item_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my_package.custom_views.FontTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_spinner"
    style="@style/App_TextViewStyleSmall"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="inherit" />
    <!--declared in layout: item_spinner.xml-->
    <!-- removed attributes:  android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textColor="@color/text_grey_light"
               android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14" -->
    <!--style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"-->
```

step 2: declare item_spinner_dropdown.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my_package.custom_views.FontTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_spinner"
    style="@style/App_TextViewStyleSmall"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:singleLine="true" />
    <!--declared in layout: item_spinner_dropdown.xml -->
    <!--removed: ?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight-->
    <!--style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"-->
```

Step 3: Use spinner in layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fet_bus_entity"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.my_package.custom_views.FontTextView
                style="@style/App_TextViewStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:text="@string/are_you_a" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_my_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[Note: id of the FontTextView is same in both the layouts, spinner item and drop down item]

Step 4: use it in the Activity/Fragment:

```
private void initSpinnerBusinessType(View rootView) {
        String[] ar_dd_bus_type = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ar_dd_bus_type);
        List<String> lst_bus_type = Arrays.asList(ar_dd_bus_type);
        ArrayList<String> ar_bus_type = new ArrayList<>(lst_bus_type);
        //==

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.item_spinner, R.id.tv_spinner, ar_bus_type);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout
                .item_spinner_dropdown);
        //=========
        Spinner sp_my_spinner= rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp_my_spinner);
        sp_my_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[ for further guidance see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51077569/787399 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164007/787399 ]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow basic customization of FontTextView, FontEditView, FontRadioButton, FontCheckBox and FontButton.

[ For the exact answer, after seeing this guide, please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113022/787399   ]

Use custom FontTextView, in ArrayAdapter item layout, like this:

```
public class FontEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

//    private String FONT = "fonts/roboto_regular.ttf";

    public FontEditText(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
//        setFontFromAsset(context, null, R.style.DefaultFontTextView);
//        FONT = getContext().getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular);
    }

    public FontEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFontFromAsset(context, attrs, R.attr.fetFontStyle);
    }

    public FontEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setFontFromAsset(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void setFontFromAsset(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        BaseActivity activity = (BaseActivity)((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();
        FontAndLocaleManager fontAndLocaleManager = activity.getFontAndLocaleManager();
        fontAndLocaleManager.setFontFromAsset(this, R.styleable.FontEditText, R.styleable.FontEditText_fetFontFace, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

use the code:

```
public void setFontFromAsset(View view, int[] resViewStyleable, int resStyleableViewFontFace, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        String strFont = null;
        Typeface tfFontFace = null;
        String strButton = FontButton.class.getCanonicalName(),
                strTextView = FontTextView.class.getCanonicalName(),
                strEditText = FontEditText.class.getCanonicalName(),
                strView = view.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        try {
            if (view.isInEditMode()) {
                return;
            }
            //R.string.font_roboto_regular
            strFont = context.getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular);
            tfFontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), strFont);

            //AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes
            //R.styleable.FontButton
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, resViewStyleable, defStyle, 0);
            //R.styleable.FontButton_btFontFace
            String derivedFont = a.getString(resStyleableViewFontFace);

            a.recycle();

            //==
            try {
                if (derivedFont != null) {
                    Typeface derivedFontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), derivedFont);
                    if (strView.equals(strButton)) {
                        ((FontButton) view).setTypeface(derivedFontFace);
                    } else if (strView.equals(strTextView)) {
                        ((FontTextView) view).setTypeface(derivedFontFace);
                    } else if (strView.equals(strEditText)) {
                        ((FontEditText) view).setTypeface(derivedFontFace);
                    }
                    return;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (strFont != null && tfFontFace != null) {
                if (strView.equals(strButton)) {
                    ((FontButton) view).setTypeface(tfFontFace);
                } else if (strView.equals(strTextView)) {
                    ((FontTextView) view).setTypeface(tfFontFace);
                } else if (strView.equals(strEditText)) {
                    ((FontEditText) view).setTypeface(tfFontFace);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Describe style and attributes in respective xmls:

```
<!--FontTextView-->
    <declare-styleable name="FontTextViewStyle">
        <!-- Style of the FontTextView. -->
        <attr name="ftvFontStyle" format="reference"/>

    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FontTextView">
        <!-- Font face of FontTextView. -->
        <attr name="ftvFontFace" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

and

```
<!--FontTextView-->
<style name="StyledFontTextView" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
<item name="ftvFontStyle">@style/DefaultFontTextView</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultFontTextView">
<item name="ftvFontFace">@string/font_roboto_regular</item>
</style>
```

define some more styles:

```
<style name="App_TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp_20</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
    <style name="App_TextViewStyleMedium" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_hint</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp_18</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
    <style name="App_TextViewStyleSmall" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_grey_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp_14</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

mention fonts in your strings.xml:

```
...
<string name="font_roboto_regular">fonts/roboto_regular.ttf</string>
...
```

and use in the layouts saving some code and time:

```
<com.mypackage.custom_views.FontTextView
                style="@style/App_TextViewStyleMedium"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                app:fetFontFace="@string/font_roboto_regular"
                android:text="@string/are_you_a" />
```

At Android level 16 and above, all this is simplified, because now you can keep TTF and other font resources in `/res/font` folder, rather than in assets. That removes most of the custom classes, styles and attributes, see:

[Font Resources in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource)

Happy Coding with style!! :-)

Comment: Long answer, but one time work. Then after that this is a reusable.

Answer (score -1):

Guys I found an awesome solution, I wrap orignal adapter by helper like

Use this class [SpinnerViewHelper](https://gist.github.com/Qamar4P/739dfd7e57d63a16693c3ab984ebdc57) and happy progamming with Android

```
new SpinnerViewHelper((Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.labelSurveyNumber),(parent, v, position, id) -> UrduFontHelper.set(v));
```

Lambda expression is used.