# How might I use the "Comic Sans" font for Android's TextView?

Tags: android

How might I use the "Comic Sans" font for Android's TextView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Fonts in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android)

Comment: Also this one: [How to set font custom font to Spinner text programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483495/how-to-set-font-custom-font-to-spinner-text-programmatically)

Comment: @Jon http://www.geofffox.com/MT/archives/2006/06/04/death-to-comic-sans.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try TypeFace and one of its method Typeface.createFromAsset(). I think Only TTF type is supported. Visit [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/04/using-custom-fonts-on-android.html) link for tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:typeface` in your xml layout file to change the font.