# How to change the spinner background in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, nine-patch

I am developing an app in which I need to change the spinner background layout to match the background color. I researched and found that I need to create a 9 patch image. I have done creating the 9 patch image and used in the app but it looks bigger than the normal spinner and also I couldn't see the drop down button in the spinner as well.

I am so happy if you guys provide me a clear tutorial from start creating the 9 patch image for Spinner and using it in the app.

[image: The spinner looks like]

**Code for the Spinner**

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnIncredientone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMixtureTitle" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
        android:prompt="@string/selectmixture" />
```

Comment: [Android: Custom Spinners](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35867517/2826147) for update.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

```
android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

and if you use the drop down menu with you spinner you can set its background color like this:

```
android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

Comment: how about the text inside the dropdown menu with the spinner?

Comment: if i remember correctly, then you can only define that by the android:textcolor attribute of the spinner. So the text color in the drop down menu unfortunately has to be the same as the spinner widgets text color.

Comment: An answer like this should be at the top

Comment: Arrow disappears this way

Comment: any solution for disppeared arrow? 

Comment: @steven solution for disppeared arrow - check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552371/9427138)

Answer (score 75):

You can change background color and drop down icon like doing this way

Step1:  In drawable folder make background.xml for border of spinner.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/darkGray" />
</shape>  //edited
```

Step2: for layout design of spinner use this drop down icon or any image drop.pnj[image: use this image like as]

```
  <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".28"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@mipmap/drop" />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Finally looks like below image and it is every where clickable in round area and no need of to write click Lister for imageView.

For more details , you can see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859442/4997704)

[image]

Comment: Does it have a dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes, Looking nice Drop down menu

Comment: That works great! Can I ask why the ImageView can trigger the pull-down menu automatically?

Comment: @MikeYan , it doesn't. There is relative layout, spinner width is "match_parent", so the imageView is drawn above spinner. Image doesn't handle clicks, so they are delivered to spinner

Comment: This doesn't work when you want to have multiple spinner in one row, because match _parent will take the whole width.

Comment: @Vincent_Paing, It working in multiple spinner in one row, you have to need set weight and weight sum

Answer (score 30):

Even though it is an older post but as I came across it while looking for same problem so I thought I will add my two cents as well. Here is my version of Spinner's background with DropDown arrow. Just the complete background, not only the arrow.

This is how it looks..
[image: Screenshot of Spinner using spinner_bg.xml]

Apply on spinner like...

```
<Spinner
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg" />
```

spinner_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/InputBg" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#666666" />
                        <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa" android:width="1dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/InputBg"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`@color/InputBg` should be replaced by the color you want as your background.

First it fills the background with desired color. Then a child layer-list makes a square and rotates it by 45 degrees and then a second Rectangle with background color covers the top part of rotated square making it look like a down arrow. (There is an extra stroke in rotated rectangle with is not really required)

Comment: thanks nashe, 
but the text is not shrinking, its overlapping with down arrow.

how to shrink the text so it wont overlap the down arrow?

Comment: And do I have to do to add borders to the spinner?

Comment: instead of nested `layer-list`, i just put the image `<bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_down_24px"/>` and got the result :)

Comment: this code doesn't work in api 17. please, check it out.

Comment: attribute height and width only for api 23+

Answer (score 26):

[image: Sample Image]

> When you set the spinner background color using `android:background="@color/your_color"`   your spinner
> default arrow will disappear

And also need to add fixed width and height to spinner so you can show the full content of the spinner.

so i found a way to do it , just like the above image.

> Write your spinner code inside a frame layout, here you don't need to use a separate image view for showing drop down icon.

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Floor"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_short"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_spn_background">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownSelector="@color/colorAccent"
                android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/dp_70"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:tooltipText="Select floor" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

> Create a new xml for Frame layout background or set
> `android:background="@color/your_color"`

custom_spn_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_5" />
  <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: + for the part about the FrameLayout which should be the accepted answer once the intention is to keep the default spinner dropdown icon

Comment: This is the most simple and correct answer, rest are all complicated workarounds. OP, please accept this.

Comment: This one was the best one for me.

Comment: Very easy method and its working..

Comment: Need to add </shape>at the end of this code to fix the syntax.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

> Spinner code

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/text.white"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"/>
```

> bg_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp"  android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                        <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="1dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item android:width="20dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to create a new personalized layout for your spinner items, like this, I will name it:

spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

Then on your spinner declaration, you need to make your spinner use the new layout in the adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.layout.spinner_item, YOUR_SPINNER_CONTENT);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To personalize elements from the dropdown list, you need to create another layout, I will name it spinner_dropdown_item.xml:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

and then on the adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.layout.spinner_item, YOUR_SPINNER_CONTENT);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi Heisenberg. Given your example above, is there a way that I can make the layout_width equal to the layout_height? Thanks

Comment: This results in the loss of padding around the list items as you replaced     android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" with android:layout_height="wrap_content". Keeping the former causes an error. How can we resolve this?

Comment: how can i change the selected item colour on click

Answer (score 12):

As [Jakob pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550512/56285), `android:popupBackground` is the key attribute for the dropdown (opened state of the Spinner), but instead of using just a colour, I got the best results with a 9-patch drawable like this:

[image]
`menu_dropdown_panel.9.png`

Note that it's very easy to generate this 9-patch image for the background colour of your choice, for example using [this online tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) as I [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077381/56285)!

So, my Spinner XML definition looks like:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/navigationBlue"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel"
    />
```

And the result:

[image]

(For custom fonts, as in the screenshot above, a [custom SpinnerAdapter is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510848/56285) too.)

Works at least on Android 4.0+ (API level 14+).

Comment: Jonik, can you tell me how could you change the spinner icon?

Comment: @danigonlinea: Yep, I used a [custom spinner item layout & `android:drawableRight`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30336734/56285) (just documented that a in new answer).

Comment: Thank you @Jonik, it was really easier than I thought ;). Just I spent a lot of time looking for an option to change that in styles.xml.

Comment: Thanks, this is much simple

Answer (score 8):

spinner code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

spinner_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_enable" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"  /> <!-- enable -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"  android:state_enabled="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_disable" android:state_enabled="false" /> <!-- disable -->
</selector>
```

spinner_disable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ddf" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />

            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:width="12dp"
                android:height="12dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#ddf" />
                        <stroke
                            android:width="1dp"
                            android:color="#aaaaaa" />
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="10dp"
                android:bottom="21dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_clicked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#00f" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />

            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:width="12dp"
                android:height="12dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#00f" />
                        <stroke
                            android:width="1dp"
                            android:color="#aaaaaa" />
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="10dp"
                android:bottom="21dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_enable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00f" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#BBDEFB" />

        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#BBDEFB" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:right="8dp">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:width="12dp"
            android:height="12dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:toDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#00f" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#aaaaaa" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="10dp"
            android:bottom="21dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#BBDEFB" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

it works fine without nine-patch pictures. api 21+ 
[image]

Comment: can you add an image? using this without showing how it does look isn't a good idea.

Comment: I added. Thanks for improvement suggestion.

Comment: The code can work well, but the file names in 'spinner_selector' are wrong

Answer (score 3):

spinner_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_enabled" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false" /> <!-- enable -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_clicked" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" /> <!-- disable -->
</selector>
```

spinner_enabled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00f" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="60%"
        android:toDegrees="135">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#00f" />
                <solid android:color="#00f" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_disabled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ddf" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="60%"
        android:toDegrees="135">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#ddf" />
                <solid android:color="#ddf" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_focused.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00f" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#BBDEFB" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="60%"
        android:toDegrees="135">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#00f" />
                <solid android:color="#00f" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

it works fine without nine-patch pictures.
api 10+
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried above samples but not working for me. The simplest solution is working for me awesome:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" >
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/Area"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is already said in other answers . I did it like placing Spinner inside a CardView and changed the cardBackgroundColor . You could use some other views also and set its background either drawable or color . Thus it doesn't affect
Spinner drop down arrow. As the spinner dropdown arrow disappears if we set background to Spinner.

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
        
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to work with the transparent background in a spinner.

spinner_enable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke

                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#00aedb" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="135">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="135"
                android:pivotX="100%"
                android:pivotY="60%"
                android:toDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="10dp"
                        android:color="#00aedb" />
                    <solid android:color="#00aedb" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_disable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:left="-3dp"
    android:right="-3dp"
    android:top="-3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        <stroke

            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#d9dadc" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="60%"
        android:toDegrees="135">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="60%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#d9dadc" />
                <solid android:color="#d9dadc" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

spinner_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_enable" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"  /> <!-- enable -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_disable" android:state_enabled="false" /> <!-- disable -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_border"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/teach_repeat"
        android:entries="@array/on_off"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_white_18dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use this code

```
            <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.80">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:background="@drawable/spiner_back"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />
                </FrameLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorred"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_extrabold"
                    android:text="GO"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorwhite" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

And This is background which i used...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorwhite" />
```

and here we go this is view which i archive...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has a pre-defined code, you  can directly use it.
**android:popupBackground**="HEX COLOR CODE"