# How to change Spinner drop down image icon?

Tags: android

I want to change the default spinner drop down icon also want to change the background of it, by using which property I can do that?

I am having following spinner code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/security_ques"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt" >
</Spinner>
```

please give any solution on it

Comment: please refer the following link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android][1]

Comment: it fells irrelevant to put a image on spinner please elaborate on what u wanted...

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) for custom spinner drop down box.

They have created customized xml layout for spinner and called that layout to the spinner using these code

```
  Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_show);
  mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));
```

Comment: i just want to change the icon of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

use it in your xml

```
android:background="@drawable/your_imagename"
```

Comment: he said spinner icon not the background of the spinner !! this is a wrong answer