# Customized spinner

Tags: java, android

I have added a `spinner` in an application which gives the package information in only a word or couple of word. it seems like regular dropdown menu.
I tried to make changes in `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` file but it does not help and also it is having a radio button which i dont require.

I am done with handling functionality and only needed to change design of that dropdown menu of spinner.

for that i am using `checkedTextView` like:

```
service_provider_spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ser_menu);
```

now i don't want that layout rather i like to add a background for each item and also want to set text padding and margin and all that. How can i do this in java file specificly and also in XML.

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the spinner_layout and spinner_dropdown_layout by simply creating an xml layout for both containing only TextView like this as shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
 />
```

And you can apply this xml to your adapter as shown below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), R.layout.your_spinnerLayout, yourArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_spinner_dropdown_layout);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i also want to give a background to each item. Can i do the same in xml file with android:background="..."??