# Customizing spinners' spacing

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, android-appcompat

Spinners provide two states. The first and default state (*state A*) shows the currently selected value. The second (*state B*) shows a dropdown menu when the spinner display is touched.

[image: State A and B example]

By default a left padding is added to the items displayed in state A and B. I would like to remove it when the current selected value is displayed (*state A*) but to keep it when items are displayed in the dropdown menu (*state B*).

Since the padding is set with the *CheckedTextView* used in the layout that is specified when the spinner is created, my first try was to pass to the spinner constructor a custom layout that contains a CheckedTextView with empty padding. This way, the left padding disapears in state A but also in state B. However, my goal was to keep it for state A.

My second try was to customize *android:dropDownSpinnerStyle* in my theme definition. Since changing background color for *android:dropDownSpinnerStyle* changes the background color of the item in state A only, my thought was to override the marginLeft or paddingLeft with a negative value. Unfortunately, it has no effect.

Given that negative margin/padding seems not to be taken into account, I have tried the opposite. Firstly, I have used a custom item layout (as explained for my first try) in order to remove left padding on both states (A and B). Secondly, I have defined a custom style for property *android:dropDownListViewStyle*. Unfortunately, using a positive marginLeft value with the last property has no effect. Thus, I have set paddingLeft. It works and allows me to get the left spacing for state B only. However, the left space applies also to the background touch color (cf. image below).

[image]

I think that only the style for state A should be altered if I want to have the on touch background color that fully fills the dropdown menu width. Any idea, suggestion or example is welcomed.

Below is my theme definition for the third try:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.App">
    ...
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown.ListView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Spinner.DropDown.ListView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 35, accepted):

State A takes on the following style:

```
// Theme (Base) // Theme.AppCompat
@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem

// Holo & Holo Light
@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem
```

The attribute at play here is `spinnerItemStyle`.

Moreover, the padding provided is *not* `paddingLeft`, but `paddingStart` - to support LTR & RTL languages. Similarly, `paddingEnd` is set instead of `paddingRight`. This info applies to API >=17.

If you are using AppCompat, you will still override the `spinnerItemStyle` attribute, but provide `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`.

Example:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.App">
...
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/TextViewSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewSpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">40dp</item>
</style>
```

The `40dp` value is for testing if setting this style even works. This should only pad `State A`(with 40dp), leaving `State B` with default padding of `8dp`. Once confirmed, you can make it `0dp`, or as per your requirement.

This is the result I get:

[image]

**Update:**

In reference to the sample project - `MainActivity`:

```
spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item));
```

By giving the adapter `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`, you are telling it to use the layout for *both* State A and State B. This is a problem because of the way this layout is defined:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Notice the `style` applied to this `TextView`. Earlier, I had suggested that you override this attribute. And it worked. But since this layout is used for both the states, the outcome is not as desired.

In fact, the statement right above (though not doing anything at the moment) is more promising:

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

By using `setDropDownViewResource(int)`, you will allow the possibility of introducing different style attributes. In this case, State A will be represented by `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and State B will use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

Let's take a look at `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Now we can override another attribute - `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` - and give State B a whole different look. But, we won't. On Lollipop, `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` points to style `Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner` which sets the `paddingX` to `8dp`. And you said that you're okay with the default padding in State B.

So, here's what you need:

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// State B
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

AND, if you don't have this already, add it to values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/TextViewSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewSpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

You should also create `values-v21/styles.xml` and add:

```
<style name="TextViewSpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Unfortunately, your example updates state A and B when it is applied on Android Lollipop.

Comment: @Laurent I have added a screenshot of the code I tried. The code is running in Genymotion Lollipop preview emulator. I am not sure why it isn't working on your end. What is your base theme? Could you post all relevant parts of your `styles.xml`?

Comment: I have created a simple project to reproduce the issue. The `styles.xml` is available at https://github.com/lpellegr/android-spinner-styling-issue/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: @Laurent Thanks for uploading a sample project. I have tried to explain the issue above. I hope it helps solve your problem.

Comment: Because you are hardcoding the theme from which the spinnerItemStyle inherits, I think it is generally better to just provide a custom layout resource to replace simple_spinner_item, unless you want it to look exactly the same across all versions you support (in which case you've probably defined an entire custom theme).

Comment: It worked! I also added a custom style extending from `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined` to fix the underline padding issue