# Custom Spinner dropdown not working

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I have a custom simple_spinner_item and simpel_spinner_dropdown_item. I am setting these using the following code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, the custom style is not applied. How can I fix this?

I am overriding the default android dropdown items in my style.

However, it works if I create a new Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and override getDropdownResource.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "android" like this :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(context, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: I am overriding the default android dropdown items in my style.

Comment: @barq Even though you're overriding that, but you shouldn't write `android.R` at there. You should address your own layout file instead. Some thing like `your.package.name.R.layout.your_layout_file`

Comment: I don't understand how that would be possible, because I have a style that contains the attributes, not an xml file.

Comment: It doesn't find package.R.layout.simple_spinner_item or R.layout.simple_spinner_item. But I am importing the R in my own package.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of android.R.files you have to include your project R.files for custom layout.

Comment: I am overriding the default android dropdown items in my style.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Setting parent theme worked for me. for separate item and dropdown file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213328/7735068