# Android spinner doesn't look right

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change the appearance of my spinner. Here's how it currently looks like

[image]

Here's how I want to look like -

[image]

Please suggest me how can I make this change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize a Spinner in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own style for your spinner.

There is no another way to change somethings in it design.
How to do that, you can find as example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)