# Android Spinner: Remove Extra White Space Between Text and Dropdown Icon

Tags: android, whitespace, android-spinner, dropdown

I have **a spinner** and by default there is extra **white-space** between text and *dropdown icon* which I really don't like and wanna remove it.

Tried searching over the web but did not get anything which could help me. Anybody here who has done it earlier?

[image: Spinner]

Comment: Customize Spinner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)

Comment: Neither of the solution there worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did it myself after playing with Spinner. Here is the solution which worked pretty well.

First create a Dropdown with indicator image of your choice.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"/>
</item>
<item
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</item></layer-list>
```

Then assign it to the background of Spinner.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/basket_spinner_item_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown"/>
```

Now, adjust the padding and alignment of spinner item as per your requirement.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/simple_spinner_text_quantity"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="25dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
```

Comment: A good start. I needed to add `android:right="24dp"` on the first item and `android:left="24dp"`on the second item to prevent the text to colide with the icon.

Comment: I gave the android:right="24dp" & android:left="24dp" still the text is colliding with the drawable icon. Any solution please?

Comment: From where do you get @drawable/ic_dropdown?

Answer (score 7):

set gravity to end and adjust it with an appropriate value :

```
  android:gravity="end"
  android:paddingEnd="20dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add the following attribute to your spinner xml element:

For API < 17:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

For API => 17:

```
android:gravity="end"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quickfix**

```
android:layout_marginStart="-40dp"
```

play with negative margin, according to need. inside you spinner item xml

Comment: Negative margins are not at all recommended. If you ever need to use negative margins, you are doing it wrong!

Comment: @Ashu indeed , that's why i wrote quickfix, i am still looking for solution. if found any please send me link, thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg maybe adding "Quickfix! Not Recommended" would be helpful for beginners who might use it without being fully aware of the consequences.!

Comment: @Ashu thank you, i completely agree with your thought,  i noted it down for future.you can also take a quick read of policies of stackoverflow to know what is recommended or what not.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for Quick fixed

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:entries="@array/almanac"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_marginStart="-9dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason giving `padding:20dp` solved the problem for me. Also, play with the values of `translationX` to adjust the position of the dropdown icon. At last, you can use `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginRight` to move the whole dropdown accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Remove padding of spinner in xml

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="0dp"     
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner">
```

SpinnerAdapter or your Adapter class should be customized according to fit your needs.

```
SpinnerAdapter.getView(position, convertView, parent)    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setPadding(0, view.getPaddingTop(), view.getPaddingRight(), view.getPaddingBottom());
        return view;
}
```

Change style attribute in your spinner list item layout