# spinner title having extra white space at top and bottom

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner

I am creating custom spinner with custom array adapter.To show the spinner header title I am inflating different layout for the first position

```
public View getDropDownView(int aPosition, View aConvertView, ViewGroup aParent) {

        View v = null;
        if (aPosition == 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_header, aParent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_header_text);
            tv.setText(getItem(aPosition));
        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown, aParent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
            tv.setText(getItem(aPosition));
        }


        return v;
    }
```

Layout for spinner activity:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">
        // Other form controls
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_origin_sort"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"></Spinner>
            //Other form controls
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for spinner item(spinner_item_dropdown):

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="123"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

Layout for spinner dropdown header(spinner_dropdown_header.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/text_color"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_header_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The output I am getting is:
[image]

As highlighted The view is having some extra white space at the top and bottom.Expected output is spinner downdown without white strip at top and bottom.I have not applied any padding and margin for the spinner items.How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Can you show your activity xml ?

Comment: @CagriYalcin Please check the updated question.

Comment: Can you try to change your TextView's `layout_height` to `match_parent` in `spinner_dropdown_header.xml` ?

Comment: @CagriYalcin i tried it but unfortunately getting same result

Comment: Can you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45935846/7482319) ?