# How to remove extra whitespace in Spinner android?

Tags: java, android, margin, android-spinner, padding

See Attached below image I want to get rid of extra white space after +41 because the Mobiltelefonnummer text gets trim.

[image]

Tried adding
 `android:padding="0dp"` and `android:marginStart="0dp"` and also added below code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       v.setPadding(0, v.getPaddingTop(), 0, v.getPaddingBottom());
       return v;
   }
```

The above code dint worked at all

//layout

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
```

//textview.xml

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/simple_spinner_text_quantity"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    />
```

Comment: Not sure, but setting `clipToPadding` to false, might do the trick

Comment: tried dint worked

Comment: Have your appiled to `Spinner`? or item?

Comment: I have applied to spinner

Comment: post your layout file.

Comment: @AIK I have added layout code

Comment: try this android:textAlignment="right" and see what happens and tell me.

Comment: @AIK tried din work.I want to get rid of extra whitespace so the Mobiltelefonnummer text gets adjusted

Comment: try with android:gravity="right"

Comment: Refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45935846/3974530

Comment: @AIK Still din worked

Comment: @InsaneCat I had refered the same post, din worked

Comment: Is it a custom spinner? If it is then please also post the textview.xml used for this spinner.

Comment: no, its not a custom spinner

Comment: post the textview.xml which is used inside the spinner.

Comment: @AIK added the textview code

Comment: remove all paddings from textview.

Answer (score 0):

Remove left-right padding from `TextView` or make it smaller, like `5dp`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove left padding and right padding from textview and your issue will be solved.