# How to implement custom spinner

Tags: android

I want to implement one custom spinner for app where items will be countries name which will come from server. The name comes as ascending order which I want but I also want that India will come at first row of item.

```
 // for country spinner
    StringRequest sR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, country_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(response.trim().split(",")));
                    arr.add(0, "Select Country");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditDetails6.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
                    spinPCountryName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What you have tried ? What is the issue ?

Comment: I tried above code where countries name is coming as ascending order but I want that India comes at first position of item

Comment: Then remove this _arr.add(0, "Select Country");_

Comment: I need India after select Country

Comment: Easiest method is you can delete India from your country list from server, and add manually as you are adding Select Country in 0th position. Add India in 1st position.

Comment: We can't delete from server because there is website which is working properly if I delete from server side then India will not come on website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16694786/2104990

Possible duplicate of custom spinner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove India from list, then add it to first position, Write following logic for this:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(response.trim().split(",")));
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr.get(i).equals("India")) {
                    arr.remove(i);
                }
            }
            arr.add(0, "India");
            arr.add(0, "Select Country");
```