# Spinner item to show custom object fields

Tags: android, spinner

I have a Spinner and I am using an ArrayAdapter to populate it. I want to be able to show the custom object's fields inside each spinner item:

[image: spinner with custom object fields]

The image looks a bit blurred but it contains "Savings", "account number", and Balance as fields of the Custom Objects.

How can I show it exactly like that?

Comment: refer this [example](http://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your custom XML layout file (in your `app/res/layout/` folder) for a spinner item

   This should contain 3 `TextView`'s , with each `TextView` displaying the fields of your custom object (so 1 TextView for "Savings", 1 for "account number" and another for "balance". You can, of course, modify these depending on your custom object.
2. Create a custom Adapter class that extends from `ArrayAdapter<String>`

   You will need to override both `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` to inflate the Spinner with your newly created layout.

   ```
   @Override
   public @NonNull View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

       final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_spinner_item, parent, false);

       TextView savingsTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_savings);
       TextView accountNumberTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_account_number);
       TextView balanceTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);

       CustomObject object = objectsList.get(position);

       // Format your fields to strings here
       savingsTV.setText(object.getSavings());
       accountNumberTV.setText(object.getAccountNumber());
       balanceTV.setText(object.getBalance());

       return view;
   }
   ```
3. Set up your custom adapter's list to your `List<CustomObject>` in Activity

   ```
   spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, getList());
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

[Here is a good example](http://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout) on how it is made.