# Android: Down arrow disappears after setting spinner background

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I have a rectangle box that I set the spinner background as but I would like to keep the down arrow that comes along with the spinner.  Here is my code for the rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#80000000" />
<padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
```

See the picture below:

[image]

On the left is what i currently have, on the right is what I'm trying to achieve or at least have a down arrow in there somewhere.  Any ideas on how to create this background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code with the help of uiautomator and the spinner dropdown arrow does not show up with the background set.

You could use a LayerList and have a bitmap with gravity right. Now the bitmap is part of the background set to spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#80000000"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"/>

</shape>
</item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Result :

Of course there is no border around the bitmap. You can check this link [How to change the spinner background design and color for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android) and see if it fits your requirement

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to change the size of the bitmap?  its too big and setting the layout width and height to certain values doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user1197993 http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. check the docs see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Spinner` inside a `RelativeLayout`.
In my case, the icon disapper because of parent layout's height and width.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/startbg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timerSpin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:pointerIcon="arrow"
         />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the below XML code to achieve what you need. It is similar to what *Raghunandan* posted / answered, but with some minor tweaks. Hope this will help you,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape android:thickness="2dp">
          <gradient android:angle = "90" android:endColor = "#ffffff" android:startColor = "#ffffff" android:type = "linear"/>

          <stroke android:width = "1dp" android:color = "#80000000"/>

          <corners android:radius = "5dp"/>

          <padding android:bottom = "3dp" android:left = "3dp" android:right = "3dp" android:top = "3dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>

      <item>
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees = "90"
           android:pivotX = "85%"
           android:pivotY = "50%"
           android:toDegrees = "90">
          <shape
             android:shape = "line"
             android:thickness="2dp"
             android:top = "1dp">
            <stroke
               android:color="#80000000"
               android:width = "1dp"/>
          </shape>
        </rotate>
      </item>
      <item>
        <bitmap

           android:gravity = "center|right" android:src = "@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015"/>

      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

use the required drawable in the placeholder images i added in the code.

Hope this will help you,

Good Luck