# how to change this black popup background in android

Tags: android

[image]

Hello guys, i'm facing a bug. i put `popupBackground="@color/white"` it works. but, I'm not able to change the behind popup black color. so guys please help me to solve this.

in .xml

```
<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_Empgender"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:popupBackground="@color/white"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

in coading

```
    public void setGender_Data() {
    ArrayList<Static_Spinner_Data> GenderList = new ArrayList<>();
    GenderList.add(new Static_Spinner_Data("-1", "Select Gender"));
    GenderList.add(new Static_Spinner_Data("0", "Male"));
    GenderList.add(new Static_Spinner_Data("1", "Female"));
    GenderList.add(new Static_Spinner_Data("2", "Others"));
    ArrayAdapter<Static_Spinner_Data> Genderadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Static_Spinner_Data>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, GenderList);
    Genderadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinner_Empgender.setAdapter(Genderadapter);
}
```

drawable/ spinner_background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/white" />
</item>
<item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="1dp">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:toDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: show your code snippet .

Comment: add `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: what is @drawable/spinner_background plse show the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250598/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I'm trying to change black color. which is come with white color as you can see. there is sky color is my activity background and white color is spinner popup background.but that black color i dont want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new resource file and add this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/color_primary" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Then set it as popupBackground