# Change background and item color of a spinner

Tags: android, colors, spinner

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the background color and the item color on the `spinner`?

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_categoryselect"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this my friend

```
android:popupBackground="#000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
     ...
     android:background="#YOUR_COLOR"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following attribute in your `<spinner>` tag

```
android:background="#000000"
```

If you want to change the background color for drop-down menu then

```
android:popupBackground="#000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change popup background color:

Use android:popupBackground on the Spinner in your XML or setPopupBackgroundResource(int) in code.

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android) Dupllicate question