# Trying to set spinner background white

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to set my spinner's backgroundcolour to white, and for the white spinner to sit on top of a relative layout  blue coloured box, but when I set the spinner background colour to white, the spinner disappears on the design view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="#F5F8FF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="392dp"
        android:background="#23C4C4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should check whether the Spinner item background is white or not.

Comment: do you want to set background to spinner or spinner item?

Comment: background to spinner, not item @KaranMer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can create like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    />
```

And another way you can create custom spinner this link helps you

[How to change the spinner background design and color for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you're doing it wrong you can't just set it's background from spinner tag you need to create a seperate xml design file and attach with your adapter. 
Here's a sample code.

In your java class do this:

```
List<String> listSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
                listSpinner.add("Select A Action");
                listSpinner.add("Start");
                listSpinner.add("Pause");
                listSpinner.add("Move To QA");
                listSpinner.add("Finish");
                final ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,listSpinner);
                a.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
                //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
                Spinner spinner = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sptaskstatus);
                spinner.setAdapter(a);
```

Note:
Spinner_Background_item will set background to your spinner

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Use spinner_item.xml to change text color or text appearance of your spinner item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```