# How do I achieve having a dropdown list in an edittext? NOTE: I don't want to use spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

Say "I want users to select from a dropdown list while filling a form, e.g Sex". Can I achieve exactly what is in the image attached? If yes, how?

[image]

Comment: Why not a spinner?

Comment: use spinner and add background same as edittext. you will get the same effect.

Comment: `Spinner` is idle solution for this Since its gender and you do not enter it manually . [You can change Spinner apperience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android) OR You can use use `ListPopUpWindow` other than `Spinner`

Comment: You can use spinner with custom style https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859442/5815673 or set drawable as per your requirement on EditText and on click open popup Menu or any list as per your requirement

Comment: Spinner is the best solution.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, I thought I won't be able to achieve it using spinner.

Comment: @Tee-Boi - Spinner is for the exact same scenario you are looking for.

Comment: @ADM That reference was just perfect for me... Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rohit5k2, Yes, I just realized that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an arrow image as drawable-right/drawable-end. Set focusable properties and cursor visibility false and on click of Edit text open a dialog with list. For the background use same background you are using for email-address edittext.
   Below is Sample XML Code

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCustomerType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/editTextTextColor"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/editTextTextColor"
            android:textColorHint="@color/editTextTextColor"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/editTextTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do:

The XML files should be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/sex"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `MainActivity.java` should be

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] sex = { "Male", "Female" };



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                //Create Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, sex);
                //Find TextView control
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.sex);
        //Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
                acTextView.setThreshold(1);
                //Set the adapter
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm really grateful. But I don't just want the user to type anything. I want the user to click on the edittext and select his/her gender

Comment: Then you should use the spinner.