# How to set dropdown arrow in spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I tried to set spinner with drop down arrow but i couldn't fix it can anyone help me with this? I have attached the source code.

my class file:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

        public class topup extends Activity  {
            Spinner spinner,spin1,spin2,spin3;
                EditText ed,ed1;
                Button btn;
                List<String> list, list1,list2,list3;
                    private String[] countries_list={"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};

                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.topup);


                        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                        spin1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                        spin2= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
                        spin3= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
                        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                        list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("");
                        list.add("select");
                        list.add("01");
                        list.add("02");
                        list.add("03");
                        list.add("04");
                        list.add("05");
                        list.add("06");
                        list.add("07");
                        list.add("08");
                        list.add("09");
                        list.add("10");
                        list.add("11");
                        list.add("12");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        //adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                        spinner.setAdapter(adp);


                        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            //@Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                 String item = spinner.getItemAtPosition(1).toString();
                                 //Toast.makeText(spinner.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 String ss=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                 String 
                            }


                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/red">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent" 
         />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter card number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/red">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="enter cvv" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/red" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"

      />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Add Amount" 
        android:background="@drawable/buttonsty"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Link is expired and instead redirects to a malicious site. Careful when clicking

Answer (score 25, accepted):

copy and paste this xml instead of your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/red">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent" 
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
         />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter card number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/red">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
             />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="enter cvv" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/red" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
      />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Add Amount" 
        android:background="@drawable/buttonsty"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wow, it works thank you. But have to change the background color is that possible?

Comment: if you want to change background color , you can use image as background

Comment: A description of what have you done would be really useful, together with an explanation why.

Answer (score 79):

Basically one needs to create a custom background for a spinner. It should be something like this:

spinner_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <layer-list>

            <item>
                <color
                    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            </item>

            <item>
                <bitmap
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"/>
            </item>

        </layer-list>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Then create a custom style for your spinner, where you specify the above selector as background:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Spinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
</style>
```

And finally in your app theme you should override two attributes if you want it to be applied all across your app:

```
<item name="spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.App.Spinner</item>
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.App.Spinner</item>
```

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: Oh! It's a best solution I've ever met)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working for me perfectly. Plus as the others have said, this is very simple and quick to implement compared to the other answers posted in here and in other duplicate questions.

Comment: If you don't know where **<style> </style>** tags have to be added: It's in the _res > values > styles.xml_ file. And change the name with yours (arbitrary name).

Comment: Make sure icon is not in .xml format. Otherwise, It will show caution image and app will crash. PNG or JPEG will work.

Comment: when the layout direction changed to RTL the icon will still in the right, is there any solution?

Answer (score 53):

As a follow-up to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25523712/56285), I was asked how I changed the spinner icon to get something like this:

[image]

One pretty easy way is to use a **custom spinner item layout**:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        R.layout.view_spinner_item,
        ITEMS
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In `res/layout/view_spinner_item.xml`, define a TextView with **`android:drawableRight`** pointing to the desired icon (along with any customisations to text size, paddings and so on, if you wish):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Custom spinner item layout -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
    />
```

(For the opened state, just use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` or similarly create a customised layout if you want to tweak every aspect of your spinner.)

To get the background & colours looking nice, set the Spinner's `android:background` and `android:popupBackground` [as shown in that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android). And if you were wondering about the custom font in the screenshot above, [you'll need a custom SpinnerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510848/56285).

Comment: the key of success here is to call `setDropDownViewResource` with a different layout than the one fed to the adapter through constructor. Otherwise, everything you do on the spinner inside xml is null. Android will just discard everything and use the one layout fed to the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor for both collapsed and expanded state

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the arrow moves left and right as you select different items from the list, depending on the length of the text. Anyway to fix it to the right, as the regular spinner behaves?

Comment: I had my custom arrow and default arrow too

Comment: use `android:background="@null"`  for spinner to remove default icon

Answer (score 22):

One simple way is to wrap your Spinner + Drop Down Arrow Image inside a Layout. Set the background of Spinner as transparent so that the default arrow icon gets hidden. Something like this:

```
 <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="showDropDown"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_down_blue" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here background.xml is a drawable to produce a box type background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#BDBDBD" />
</shape>
```

The above code produces this type of a Spinner and icon.

[image: Spinner with a custom drop down arrow]

Comment: in the activity.java

Answer (score 8):

Attach a Spinner Style using Java Code:

First, you need to a layout file such as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

Let us name it spinner_item.xml and place it inside res/layouts folder.

Next, Create a String ArrayList and put all the Spinner options inside it:

```
ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArray.add("Item No. 1");
spinnerArray.add("Item No. 2");
spinnerArray.add("Item No. 3");
spinnerArray.add("Item No. 4");
```

Finally, create the Spinner object and attach the style layout to it.

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
spinner.setTag("some_id");
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);                  spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Note the Spinner(getActivity()) in the above line will be changed to Spinner(this) if you are writing this from inside Activity rather than from inside a fragment.

Thats all!

---

Attach a Spinner Style inside Android Layout File:

First, create a  xml file the defines the style attribute (gradient_spinner.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90"  android:type="linear" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorBackground" />

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
        </shape></item>
        <item android:right="5dp">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center_horizontal|right" android:src="@drawable/expand_icon">
            <padding android:right="2dp" />
        </bitmap>
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>

</selector>
```

Next, inside the style.xml file specify the style and call the gradient_spinner as background

```
<style name="spinner_style">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
<item name="android:layout_margin">1dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Finally, attach the above style to the Spinner:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/agent_id_spinner"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_view"
   style="@style/spinner_style"  />
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `vector` icon and not bitmap, you can set it this way.

```
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:centerColor="#65FFFFFF" android:centerY="0.2" android:endColor="#00FFFFFF" android:startColor="@color/light_gray" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/darkGray" />
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/edit_text_corner_radius" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:right="5dp"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:drawable="@drawable/gardify_spinner_dropdown_icon"/>

    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                   <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Dropdown arrow image to spinner like this :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Exam_Course"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here  android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg" the spinner_bg is the Dropdown arrow image.

Comment: That will set the background on all the items in the spinner!

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this xml to show as a Dropdown and change your Dropdown color

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/red">

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent" 
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/textbox"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down_large"

     />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="enter card number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/red">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:popupBackground="@drawable/textbox"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down_large"
         />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/textbox"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down_large"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter cvv" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/red" >
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/textbox"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down_large"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Add Amount"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonsty"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API level 16 and above, you can use following code to change the drop down icon in spinner.
just goto onItemSelected in setonItemSelectedListener and change the drawable of textview selected like this.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  // give the color which ever you want to give to spinner item in this line of code               
//API Level 16 and above only. 
           ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,ContextCompat.getDrawable(Activity.this,R.drawable.icon),null);
 //Basically itis changing the drawable of textview, we have change the textview left drawable.

}
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
    });
```

hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

dummy.xml (drawable should be of very less size. i have taken 24dp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list android:opacity="transparent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:width="100dp" android:gravity="right" android:start="300dp">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/down_button_dummy_dummy" android:gravity="center"/>
            </item>
</layer-list>
```

layout file snippet

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        >
     <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy">

     </Spinner>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[click here to see resultant rendered layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORNK3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check below sample code.

```
<FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/genderEdt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#EEEEEE"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/drop_down_arrow"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>
```