# Changing Spinner Colours - Android

Tags: android, spinner

I have a Spinner and I want the text, and small triangle in the bottom right hand corner to be white as I intend on having a black background.

I know how to change the text colour to white but have no way of changing the small triangle image.

Help appreciated

Comment: you can set custom view for it

Comment: I dont quite know what that means.  You have an explanation or a link you can point me to?

Comment: no just read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422802/how-to-set-dropdown-arrow-in-spinner and this http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/ you just need to make a custom xml drawable, and a theme and define it in the layout xml.