# android: Where can i get the spinner image (the right angled triangle) that is on the right hand corner of the spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

Where can i get the spinner image (the right angled triangle) that is on the right hand corner of the spinner? Please give me the link of it so i can download and add it in my spinner[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set dropdown arrow in spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422802/how-to-set-dropdown-arrow-in-spinner)

Comment: no no.. here i only want to find the image.. so i can set in on my spinner

Comment: Did you find this? I am confused too. I looked in the system resources and found btn_dropdown_normal.9.png which looks the same on all versions. The straight-down triangle. I need this icon to save space. btn_dropdown.xml state list is here http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_dropdown.xml

Answer (score 0):

[abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cast-unity-plugin/raw/master/end_project/Assets/Plugins/Android/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png).
You can find more icons. [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cast-unity-plugin/tree/master/end_project/Assets/Plugins/Android/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi)

Comment: Hi, Nir.. thank you for replying.. but that is not the right image