# How to inflate a Vector inside a Selector of a Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-vectordrawable, android-selector

In my app, I'm having this spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner">
</Spinner>
```

For the background, I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        //Colors, Shapes and other details

        <item >
            <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_24dp" />
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

And for `ic_arrow_drop_down_24dp`, I use:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#008577"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M7,10l5,5 5,-5z"/>
</vector>
```

And I'm getting:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class Spinner

So I guess the error is because I'm inflating a vector and not bitmap. How to inflate a vector? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the shape element in @drawable/spinner like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793514/7507788 ?

Comment: @GiorgioBertolotti I don't get the point. Can you please explain to me?

Comment: I was pointing out that the only difference I see between the xml used for the spinner in your question and the one used in the answer I linked is that in your code there is an "item" tag missing inside the "layer-list" tag, I tought that this could be the problem... I don't see any other difference

Comment: @GiorgioBertolotti Yes, the `"item" tag` did the trick. I think you should add it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll do it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@drawable/spinner` is missing the `item` tag which specifies the shape and the colors of the `spinner`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.