# How to change text color and font of a spinner in a android app

Tags: android, fonts, colors, spinner

i need to know how to change the text color and font of a spinner in as detail as you can what points i need to change in code where do i have to paste it.. thanks in advance

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/light4text"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.15"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:theme="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:background="#1d1d1d"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/light3text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/light3text" />
```

Comment: Did you research this on your own by doing a web search?

Comment: For _How to change the font_, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5483495/450534